# Sum year, month and day - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

One year = 365 days, one month = 31 days

```
Select 1 as year, 5 as month, 10 as day from dual
union all
Select 1 as year, 10 as month, 25 as day from dual
```

Need resault as:

```
years  month  day
3      4      4
```

Comment: The question itself doesn't make a lot of sense, because the same number of days may be represented in different ways. For example, 1 year and 3 days equalt 368 days. 11 months and 27 days also equals 368 days. So, if a sum equals 368 days, how should it be represented in the output - as 1 year and 3 days, or 11 months and 27 days? Until you answer this, all solutions are wrong by definition.

Comment: That makes the assumption that 1 year = 12 months (and is not one of the OP's assumptions). If 1 year = 11 months 24 days = 365 days then there is no ambiguity as 11 months 27 days = 1 year and 3 days.

Comment: Could you please point out the purpose of these strange calculations instead of just using the function ADD_MONTHS(x)?

Comment: @JonasMetzler `ADD_MONTHS` only works for an integer number of months. If you want to add years, months and days then you need to start from a fixed date otherwise, when you add days, you do not know if the month has 28, 29, 30 or 31 days and when to wrap into the next month. Instead, when you are working with abstract year-month-day intervals you approximate what the relationship is between years, months and days and know that it is only an rough approximation that does not actually hold true to Earth's calendar. Other approximations include 1 year = 12 months = 360 days (30 per month).

Comment: @MT0 - what "makes the assumption that 1 year = 12 months"? If you are referring to my example, it does not make such an assumption. It is based exclusively on 1 year = 365 days and 1 month = 31 days. 365 + 3 = 11*31 + 27 - there is nothing about "12" in this trivial equality. And my point is, the OP should tell us which of those two representations should be given as "the answer"; otherwise the problem is ambiguous, and any solution that doesn't state explicitly which of different, equally correct answers will be returned, can't be correct.

Comment: @mathguy The problem is that you have made the assumption that 11 months + 27 days should not equal 1 year + 3 days and that if it does then there is some ambiguity. If 1 year is identical to 11 months + 24 days then there is no ambiguity as 1 year + 3 days = 11 months + 27 days = 368 days. If you instead apply the preconception from Earth's calendar that 1 year = 12 months (and not 11 months 24 days) then you get ambiguity when 1 year + 3 days could either be 12 months + 3 days or 368 days (which is 11 months 27 days). Don't assume 1 year = 12 months and there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1 year = 365 days and 1 month = 31 days then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SUM(year*365 + month*31 + day)/365) AS years,
       TRUNC(MOD(SUM(month*31 + day), 365)/31) AS month,
       MOD(MOD(SUM(month*31 + day), 365), 31) AS day
FROM
(
  Select 1 as year, 5 as month, 10 as day from dual
  union all
  Select 1 as year, 13 as month, 25 as day from dual 
) t1;
```

Which outputs:

> | YEARS | MONTH | DAY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 7 | 11 |

---

If 1 year = 12 months and 1 month = 31 days then you want:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SUM(year + month/12 + day/31/12)) AS years,
       TRUNC(MOD(SUM(month + day/31), 12)) month,
       MOD(SUM(day) , 31) day
FROM
(
  Select 1 as year, 5 as month, 10 as day from dual
  union all
  Select 1 as year, 13 as month, 25 as day from dual 
) t1;
```

Which outputs:

> | YEARS | MONTH | DAY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 7 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0f958a7aa77fcb5b7386c2efb01e9a26)*

Comment: @mathguy I was in the middle of fixing it when you commented. Its updated now.

Comment: You may want to take a look at my comment directly under the original question. With the OP's assumptions, the output is ambiguous; so you may want to edit again to explain all the assumptions you made. For example: does 11 months, 0 days PLUS 0 months, 27 days equal 11 months, 27 days? Or does it equal 1 year, 0 months, 3 days?

Comment: @mathguy Both are simultaneously true and not necessarily ambiguous as, in the OP's case 1 year = 11 months 24 days (and does not equal 12 months). It is only if the OP is trying to approximate Earth's calendar and is also assuming that 1 year = 12 months that they have a problem of ambiguity since it is mathematically impossible to have 12 31-day months total 365 days.

Answer (score 1):

We can use some algorithm to calculate the number of days, based on conditions

- `one year = 365 days`
- `one month = 31 days`

1. Year : (year * 365 + month * 31 + day) and division by 365 to get the total year of number.
2. Month : (month * 31 + day) and division by 31 to get the total month of number, but we need to get mod from that because total month numbers will be carried if that higher than 12.

as this query.

```
select CAST(SUM((year * 365 + month * 31 + day) / 365) AS INT) years  ,
       CAST(MOD(SUM(month * 31 + day)/31, 12) AS INT) month,
       MOD(SUM(day) , 31) day
from 
(
  Select 1 as year, 5 as month, 10 as day from dual
  union all
  Select 1 as year, 10 as month, 25 as day from dual 
) t1;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=209be3c5b27ff166443ebcf09bd5bdd6)

Comment: This solution is wrong (regardless of upvotes and the OP's wrong acceptance). Some counter-examples are trivial: if you add 6 months to itself, you get 1 year. But 1 year is 365 days, while a month is 31 days, so the result is 372 days. One of the errors in this solution (there may be more) is to assume that "12 months" equals "1 year". Downvote from me.

Comment: This is wrong as casting to an `INT` will `ROUND` and not `TRUNC`ate so anything with 6-11 months will have an extra year added.

Comment: An example of the rounding issue is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9c84d312b1d5d75cdac1fc0c35cc42f7)